# How to replicate user-explorer using dimension app_instance_id in GA4? (API)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to replicate the user-explorer technique in GA4 through google analytics API.

My goal here is to:

- get the amount of `activeUsers` per `firstUserMedium` within a specific timeframe.
- exclude the "users" that don't have at least an `averageSessionDuration` of 10 seconds

It is possible to do it via the GA4 user interface using the user-explorer & select my filters.
But I can't seem to be able to do it via API.

I also tried to use the dimension: `app_instance_id` (but it's not a valid name in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema)

Here is what I tried:

```
# Import the OS module
import os

# Import the necessary classes and functions from the Google Analytics Data API v1beta
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import (
    DateRange,
    Dimension,
    Metric,
    RunReportRequest,
    FilterExpression,
    FilterExpressionList,
    Filter,
    NumericValue,
)

# Set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'your_credential_file.json'

# Define the Google Analytics 4 property ID
property_id = '1234'

# Instantiate the BetaAnalyticsDataClient with the environment variable credentials
client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()
# Construct the request to the Google Analytics Data API
request = RunReportRequest(

    # Specify the Google Analytics 4 property
    property=f"properties/{property_id}",

    # Specify the dimension to be returned (firstUserMedium)
    dimensions=[Dimension(name="firstUserMedium")],

    # Specify the metric to be returned (activeUsers)
    metrics=[Metric(name="activeUsers")],

    # Specify the date range for the report
    date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="2023-07-01", end_date="2023-07-07")],

    # Apply a filter to the metric (activeUsers with averageSessionDuration >= 10)
    metric_filter=FilterExpression(
        and_group=FilterExpressionList(
            expressions=[
                FilterExpression(
                    filter=Filter(
                        field_name="averageSessionDuration",
                        numeric_filter=Filter.NumericFilter(
                            operation=Filter.NumericFilter.Operation.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
                            value=NumericValue(int64_value=10),
                        ),
                    )
                ),
            ]
        )
    ),
)

# Execute the report request
response = client.run_report(request)

# Print the dimension and metric values for each row in the response
for row in response.rows:
    print(row.dimension_values[0].value, row.metric_values[0].value)
```

**The problem in this code:**
it's applying the filter `averageSessionDuration` on the dimension `firstUserMedium` instead of applying to the object "user" or "app_instance_id".

How can I apply the filter to "app_instance_id"?

I also tried to look for an example here: https://github.com/googleapis/python-analytics-data/blob/main/samples/snippets/run_report_with_dimension_and_metric_filters.py but it doesn't seem to have the use case I'm looking for.